# Dual boot Ubuntu/Mac - Mac Partition gone - save data

Tags: dual-boot, mount, data-recovery

I have a partition running on my Mac alongside Ubuntu 16.04. It started recently that I could only boot into a black screen in the Mac OS and now the partition in the boot menu has completely disappeared. Since Ubuntu still runs perfectly I would like to use it to access my Mac partition and backup the data. Unfortunately I can't mount it and get the following error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Any other ideas how to possibly access the data on the Mac partition would be amazing.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You’d likely get better responses regarding the recovery of a macOS partition on [apple.se].